What would have been a good medium-term investment in 1999?
The longest stock market stagnation in recent times was in the early 2000s: first the dot-com crash, then the great recession. If someone in 1999 had bought into, say, an S&P 500 index fund, it would have lost value, regained it, lost it again, but not lastingly recovered until after more than a decade later.
What investment strategy would have been best for a hypothetical medium-term investor in the U.S. in 1999, for example one who needs to periodically withdraw from their portfolio? I don't mean buying into some odd stock cherry-picked through a time machine, but rather some actual investment strategy that could have existed at that time.

Depends on your timeframe. See past answers about investment strategies. Doing roughly a canonical 60/40 split of index funds starting in 2000 worked out just fine for me until I was ready to switch to something more nuanced.

In the long term, sure. What I meant was, something which would have still been profitable wrt the initial investment in, say, 2003 and 2010.

As stated this is a purely historical question. However, from your comments on answer I have the impression that what you actually want to ask is: 'If I believe we are currently in a similar situation as in 1999, what investment strategy should I use today?' which is a very different question.

When the stock market is top-heavy (a few large companies powering the indexes higher), as in 1999, it would be reasonable to focus more on small-cap stocks, e.g., the Russell 2000. That index rose and remained above its 1999 levels for most of the 2000s decade.

That's really useful, thanks! I see that if one were to buy in 2003, at the bottom of the dot-com crash, the Russell 2000 would have outperformed the S&P right until 2023.

Check what various mixes of these, rebalanced occasionally (once or twice a year), would do over that time period. Sometimes diversified mixes beat any single category.

I think you are trying to ask what is a good investment strategy if the tech sector of the US stock market is overvalued.
If one believes that the economy is still going up for a long time along with the tech bubble, one strategy is to invest in a US ETF that excludes the tech sector, e.g., SPXT. Another strategy is to invest in foreign markets that have a lower weight in tech, such as the European market.
If one believes a recession would be coming soon that crashes the stock market alongside with the bubble, another strategy is to invest in long-term treasury debt, which hedges economic downturns.
The above strategies also apply to an investor in 1999, without hindsight.
Please keep in mind that 1999 was only one single instance. Every bubble could be different in some way. There were 9/11, WorldCom scandal in that era, which were quite idiosyncratic. The above answer avoids fitting the performance of the investments in hindsight to an investor in 1999.

EDIT: Since your question only asked about 1999, an investor at that time couldn't have anticipated the real estate bubble that kicked in later in 2000s. The above answer assumed an investor in 1999. Once observing the real estate bubble in 2000s, the investor should change their strategy accordingly.

Thanks! But to nitpick, the 2000s had two bubbles back to back (dot-com and real estate), which meant that if you invested in 1999, you wouldn't gain much value for a whole decade.

Also, I wasn't specifically thinking about the current tech sector. It's probably overvalued and will correct at some point, but I don't see it being a crash. SPXT aims specifically at that sector, but I was hoping for a more general solution. Perhaps a DJIA index fund?

@Zzyzx "if you invested in 1999, you wouldn't gain much value for a whole decade" -- you would have gained quite a bit with the suggestion of "long-term treasury debt" since interest rates were in an extended downtrend.

@Zzyzx I don't think dot-com and real estate bubbles occurred at the same time. The real estate bubble really came up after the tech bubble crashed. Two consecutive major  bubbles also made the era unique. I don't think DJIA would make much difference (without hindsight): It still aimed at representing the broad market, but one might get "lucky" because DJIA happened to have a lower weight of the bubbled industries.

@Zzyzx When you mentioned DJIA, maybe you had a value stock index in mind (such as S&P 500 Value. I agree that in 1999 it was a good idea to invest in such an index, as the bubble mostly came from Growth stocks. But starting from the year observing the real estate bubble, I don't think this was a good idea any longer.

Not sure whether you count that as cherry picking but if you bought gold in 1999 you had decent annual returns until around 2012 (and then you had some pretty bad years from 2012 until 2020 or so). See for example here for historical gold prices.

Strange that this is downvoted.  Since 1999, gold is up about 8-9x, while the S&P 500 (specifically, SPY) is up about 6x.

Gold is volatile and unpredictable. It happens to have done well during the years in question, but then hit the doldrums throughout the 2010s. In hindsight it would have worked if bought at that particular time, though not in others. As a mid-range strategy, gold seems too risky to me.

@Zzyzx That is all true but gold is still a possible answer to your question. Note that multiple serious large scale investors do have some gold in their investment portfolio, so it is part of their investment strategy. There are also investors out there who put everything in gold. I certainly wouldn't recommend that as an investment strategy but it so happens that it would have worked fairly well in the time period of your question.
